# Entity Framework - How to handle table relationships?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have developed a fairly small asp.net MVC application using the repository pattern and Linq to Sql.  I would now like to access and update the same data using the Entity Framework, however I am having trouble understanding if my syntax is correct for table relationships in the Entity Framework.

Say I am retrieving a row of data for a User and I would also like to retrieve the User's assosiated Business (foreign key in the User table).  Right now I am doing something like this:

```
using (MyDatabaseEntities context = new MyDatabaseEntities())
{
    User user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Users.UserId == userId);

    if (!user.BusinessReference.IsLoaded)
    {
        user.BusinessReference.Load();
    }

    return user;
}
```

From the examples I've seen I should do something like this to access the business table data:

```
foreach (Business business in user.BusinessReference)
{
    var b = business;
    ViewData["BusinessName"] = b.BusinessName;                    
}
```

Am I going about this the right way?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the foreach part which does not really say what you are trying to do since you are in the loop overwriting the ViewData["BusinessName"] you are pretty much on track with what's going on.

If this is let's say a user being displayed and you want to also display some BusinessNames they should be available in the view. The boring thing with Entity Framework and the reason I chose to temporary use other solutions is the having to load the references.

a better solution in the example you provided might be:

```
using (MyDatabaseEntities context = new MyDatabaseEntities())
{
    return (from u in user.Include("Business")
            where u.UserId == userId
            select u).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Unfortunately you can't preload any references deeper than that in an easy way, in that case your need to loop through all the way and Load.

Comment: So if I use ".Include" I can't include multiple tables or relationships?  For example: 
    User user = db.User.Include("Business").Include("UserRoles").FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);

Comment: Please note that Include may not Eager load Business (Include is a "hint"/request, not a command), and you absolutely need to keep the IsLoaded/Load code.  Also, you can stack multiple Includes.

Comment: So, if I use the Include, in my controller I can now use something like this: user.Business.BusinessName.ToString(); after I load my user object.  Why do I need to use the IsLoaded/Load code also?

Comment: for this scenario you don't but you can't include any related ends of Business like this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx for more information

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't seem quite right. This would be more like it:

```
User user = db.User.Include("Business").FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
```

This assumes that your User Entity has a navigation property named Business.

Comment: I don't think this really corrects the original code, so much as requests an eager load in addition to what the original code did.  Inspecting the underlying generated SQL queries would be the only way to determine which one ended up with a "better" result.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1. Make a presentation model for your view and change the view to a strongly typed view.
2. Use L2E to project onto the presentation model.

Like this:

```
var model = (from u in Context.Users 
             where u.UserId == userId
             select new UserPresentation
             {
                 UserName = u.Name,
                 BusinessName = u.Business.BusinessName,
                 SomeOtherDatumYourViewNeeds = // ...
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Some important points here:

- You don't have to worry about eager loading. The data you need will always be loaded.
- You are not asking the SQL Server to return date a you don't need, like properties of User or Business which you don't intend to display in the view.
- Your view is now decoupled from your entity model. They can both evolve independently.

Comment: Very good suggestion, I appreciate the input!  I think this is a very good recommendation and may be what I actually end up using.  Would I still need to use the ".Include" to be able to access the u.Business.BusinessName?

Comment: No. Include is completely unnecessary when projecting.